# Laravel 5: how to safely override the default User::create() for two tables?

Tags: model, controller, laravel-5, registration

With Laravel 5.2, I would like to have a guest user provide their first and last names when signing up. The first_name and last_name fields are from a different model `People` that's basically like a table for their extended profiles:

```
Users
    id
    email
    username

People
    user_id
    first_name
    last_name
    profile
    ...
```

In the default `AuthController`, it calls the create method of User class like this:

```
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param array $data
 *
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name'     => $data['name'],
        'email'    => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

But what should I do to overwrite this method so that it creates a user by adding data to the above two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a one to one relation from User to the People model. So once you create a User, you can call the user and add details as follows:

```
$user->people()->create(['first_name]=>$request->input('first_name'));
```

Refer Laravel docs to find out how to create a one to one relation. This will give you the start.

Comment: Hi, thanks again!! I think I figured out this just now. Thanks very much for your confirmation. What I'm thinking is, instead of the return, I can define the new user, and then use your line above, and then return the $user. Is that the right way? I've already defined all the relations between models.

Comment: Yes you can do that as well.